# How can I see the value of a variable that is inside a class during python interactive mode?

Tags: python, shell, debugging, interactive

When I run a script with python -i file.py and I recieve an error, I would like to find out the value of that variable. However it is inside a class, and not an instance.

```py
class Foo:
    def func(self):
        action_dict = self.socket_resp() # a function that recieves some response from a socket. 
        print(action_dict['bar'])
```

python -i foo.py

> KeyError no 'bar' in action_dict
>
> action_dict

NameError: name 'action_dict' is not defined'

How do I get the value of the action_dict variable in interactive mode

Comment: It is not inside a class but inside a **method**

Comment: No you can't that way. Running a python program interactively is different from running it with the [interactive source code debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get it. The exception from `-i` will be available in `sys.last_value`. **First** `import sys` and save the `sys.last_value` to a variable! If you typo, the exception will be lost for good!

Then you can import the `traceback` module and inspect the activation records, which includes local variables in all call frames!

Thus we get:

```
% python3 -i file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 6, in <module>
    Foo().func()
  File "file.py", line 4, in func
    print(action_dict['bar'])
KeyError: 'bar'
>>> import sys
>>> exc = sys.last_value
>>> import traceback
>>> [*traceback.walk_tb(exc.__traceback__)][-1][0].f_locals
{'action_dict': {'foo': 'spam'}, 'self': <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f6aa2e6b978>}
```